# Is there any way to add all apt repository of Debian based Linux distros on your Debian system?

Tags: linux, apt, deb, aptitude, apt-mirror

Let's take example of Ubuntu and Kali Linux, both are based on Debian Linux. but many packages in Kali's apt sources are not available in Ubuntu's apt sources. But if we add Kali's sources and GPG-keys. Those package will be installable on Ubuntu directly by `apt install`.

I need to add all apt repositories on my Debian system so that, I can install any package from any other Debian based operating system.

EDIT: Okay, I know this is a bad idea. But what if I wanna force use it in a VM or to use it once then remove the sources. (Kali is an example what about other distros)

Comment: ["adding other operating system’s repositories into Kali (such as trying to put Ubuntu on Kali), will break your installation. This is the single most common reason why Kali Linux systems break."](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/#non-kali-repositories): This question is underresearched, as this works both ways.

Comment: If you want to use individual Kali tools on an Ubuntu system, `docker` may be your friend. It can also be useful for playing with FrankenDebian effects (mixing incompatible source repos) without hurting yourself too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn’t try to do this. The fact that other distributions are based on Debian doesn’t mean they’re compatible with Debian.

If you add Ubuntu or Kali repositories to a Debian system, you’ll end up with a [FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian) which is quite likely to fall apart sooner or later. Unix.SE regularly gets questions from people who have done just that, asking for help fixing their systems.

If you want to use Kali-specific tools on a Debian system, try running Kali in a VM.

Comment: To note that Kali, in multiple places, very clearly stresses that you cannot just add Ubuntu or Debian repos. I don't know why professional users (which is what [Kali explicitly aims at](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/)) still don't use their favourite search engine.